# Dynamic AuthorizeAttribute with database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity

I want to create a `AuthorizeAttribute` that gets the current `ActionMethod` `RouteData` and searches in a database for a user that has access to this `ActionMethod`.

I created a `UserAccessPermission` table:

```
public class UserAccessPermission
{
    [Key]
  public int  UserAccessPermissionId { get; set; }
    public string ActionMethod { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public bool HasAccess { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("User")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

and then link it to the `User` table:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        AccessPermissions = new HashSet<UserAccessPermission>();

    }
 some custome field

    //*******************************************************************

    public virtual ICollection<UserAccessPermission> AccessPermissions { get; set; }

 }
```

so each user has multi `ActionMethod` that can access it. Then I create my custom `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
  public class DynamicRoleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }


        //var rolesProvider = new RoleProvider();
        var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var controller = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        string area = null;
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var _user = _userManager.FindById(userId);

        if (routeData.DataTokens["area"] != null)
        {
            area = routeData.GetRequiredString("area");
            result = _user.AccessPermissions.Where(x => x.Controller.Equals(controller) && x.ActionMethod.Equals(action) && x.Area.Equals(area)).Select(x => x.HasAccess).FirstOrDefault();

        }
        else
        {
            result = _user.AccessPermissions.Where(x => x.Controller.Equals(controller) && x.ActionMethod.Equals(action)).Select(x => x.HasAccess).FirstOrDefault();

        }


        if (result)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
        //return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

But this approach is too hard for page management and the admin should give user access permission for each `ActionMethod`. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Designing appropriate authorization usually requires a lot more information analysis than can be offered in a Code Review question. We know nothing of the building blocks of your application, required access levels or required granularity of the authorization. I really wouldn't know where to start. "Too broad" if you ask me.

Comment: A good start could be to look at industry standards, for example claims and scopes as implemented by [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/terminology.html).

Comment: @GertArnold what do you mean by 'building blocks of your application'??

Comment: AKA aggregates: distinct parts of the application, some of which may require fine-grained authorization, some may be authorizable as a whole or are authorization-free, etc.

Comment: @GertArnold  what should i do know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
You are close, man!

You have to make relashionships between pairs of controller+action to some user actions.

For example:
Security Staff can only view Personal Info:
- View Personal

Then your HHRR Manager can:
- View Personal
- Add Personal
- Edit Personal

And finally HHRR Director he can do more actions like:

- View Personal
- Add Personal
- Edit Personal
- Delete Personl

And now in game you should include some extra tables, bro! hehehehehehe

Lets say your system has HHRR module. 
Add this module record to the **AccessModule** table. Then add 3 records to **AccessModuleActions** like

- HHRR Director
- HHRR Manager
- Security Staff

Apply ACL to each user via **PersonalModuleActions** table. Acctually you should use **PersonalModuleActions** at website admin GUI area.

And internally (no GUI for it) you will gonna use **WebSiteAccessModuleActions** table
where you keep relashionships between controller methods and those "roles".

This approach allows use

> 1) Ignore methods that are not described in **WebSiteAccessModuleActions**
>
> 2) Build very flexible ACL subsystem.

***As you see we manipulate  kinda of groups of controller methods represented in
a user friendly manner***

```
- HHRR Director
- HHRR Manager
- Security Staff
```

So when I said you are close it is just implement **one more level of abstraction**.

Enjoy, dude!

[image]

P.S. Include **Area** columnto the  **WebSiteAccessModuleActions** if you have
identical controller in several website's areas.